# Origin & explanation of sabado & sobota being similar in latin and slavic languages?

Tags: romance-languages, slavic-languages

The word for Saturday in many languages both Romance (Italian, Spanish etc.) and Slavic (Russian, Polish, for example) is Sabado / Sobota - very similar words!

---

My personal amateur guess is that it comes from the Christian religious word (in English): "sabbath" and therefore probably comes from Latin and the spread of Christianity a long time ago.

---

Is this true or are there better explanations?

Comment: It's true, they're related to *sabbath*, but it comes from Semitic not Latin, and from there into Greek. Per Ling SE rules, please Google it or use Wiktionary before asking basic etymology questions. Schabbat schalom.

Comment: Look for the Semitic root "7".

Comment: @user6726. Wrong. “Sabbath” is š-b-t; “seven” is š-b-ʻ.

Comment: See this: http://blogs.ucl.ac.uk/calendars-ancient-medieval-project/files/2015/07/SABBATH-paper.pdf

Comment: Noo, it's not fair, I called dibs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both Romance and Slavic languages it was borrowed indirectly from [Hebrew](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA) - in both cases through ancient Greek [σάββατον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CE%AC%CE%B2%CE%B2%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD) which, in turn, was borrowed to medieval Latin ([ecclesiastical Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastical_Latin), to be more precise) as [`sabbatum`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sabbatum#Latin).